# Angular js 204 response blocking in IE10

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, internet-explorer-10

NOTE: In reference to this website http://www.redbullracingshop.com.au/

I have a .net WebApi running along with angular $.http interaction on the front end. A client recently mentioned that the dynamic feature of the site have stopped working in IE.

After running the code in a few browsers and watching the requests. I noticed that in IE. The Post request were hanging or "pending" for about 2 minutes before returning a result to the client. I ran through the code with some break point on the server and the javascript to find where it was locking up, and found that the request fires fine and the server code executes as expected. Nothing is stalling here.

SERVER snippet

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public void AddToCart(JObject jsonData){
   // DO CODE
}
```

I am returning a void response, or 204. This is what i expect and don't consider this to be an error. Somewhere between the server responding and the client receiving the response, there is a 2 minute stall?

Is this an angular error maybe?

CLIENT snippet

```
this.post = function (url, data, success, fail) {
    fail = (fail !== undefined) ? fail : success;
    $http.post(url, data)
        .success(function (data) {
            if (data.length == 0) {
                success(onEmpty(url));
            } else {
                success(data);
            }
        })
        .error(function (data) {               
            fail(onError(url, data));
        });
}
```

I have investigated and found that this is only happening in IE10 and not actual version of the previous version, opposed to the emulated version from the dev console.

I am aware of IE doing some interesting stuff with 204 responses, and this might have changed in IE10. Se here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/357?source=cc

The Network inspector results are as follows:

/api/CartApi/AddToCart | POST | 204 | 295 B | 384.76 s | XMLHttpRequest

Any Ideas? If all else fails i will have to try converting all these void WebAPI responses to empty strings maybe.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js

Comment: Have you followed the instructions present in this [guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

Comment: @callmekatootie yes. I don't really think that has anything to do with this as the response never gets to the front end. This seems to only be in reference to $http.

Comment: are you sure you're sending and completing the response? or are you writing void and not completing it?

Comment: Are you using SSL by any chance? We had trouble with "pending" requests, and it turned out to be caused by a self-signed certificate that angular sometimes liked and sometimes did not.

Comment: @stu.salsbury: not sure what you mean the c# code snippet is above. the addToCart api endpoint returns void (204 No Content). aet: There is SSL on the site but none of these api endpoint are behind or make use of it. Again this only happens on IE10, all other browsers have no trouble handling the 204 responce. Try it for yourself at [link](http://www.redbullracingshop.com.au/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now the best solution I have is a work around. Don't use a void response resulting in a 204, instead return a manual HttpStatusCode.OK (200) response.

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddToCart(JObject jsonData){
   // DO CODE
   return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I am still curious for an explanation on this bug.